# Присваивание JS

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Не могу понять, как происходит присваивание в JS. Написал ~700 строчек кода, в последующем была обнаружена некорректная работа программы.
Суть в следующем:

```
  var begindate = new Date(2015,2,3,8,0,0);
  ...
  if(begindate.getHours() == 8)
  {
  var time = begindate;
  ...
  alert(begindate); // Mon Mar 3 2015 00:08:00 GMT+0300 (Московское время (зима))
  time.setHours(time.getHours() + Math.floor(gen)); //gen - случайная величина
  alert(begindate); // Mon Feb 23 2015 00:11:00 GMT+0300 (Московское время (зима))
```

Собственно, мне интересно, почему я меняю значение time, а вместе с ним меняется значение begindate?

Comment: @artyomkulakov, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что begindate и time - это переменные - ссылки, которые ссылаются на один и тот же объект.
Поэтому если поменять значение в одной переменной оно изменится и в другой.

Подробнее можно почитать здесь: http://learn.javascript.ru/object#передача-по-ссылке

Comment: И вам тоже спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

А как вы думаете, что будет меняться после этого:

```
var time = begindate;
```

Вот если бы было так написано:

```
var time = new Date(begindate);
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае, time это лишь ссылка на begindate.
Если хотите, чтобы они были отдельны, пишите так:

```
var time = new Date(begindate)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)

Answer (score 0):

1. begindate - это ссылка на экземпляр класса Date
2. Когда ты присваиваешь time = begindate то ты присваиваешь ссылку, соответственно все изменения через time меняют непосредственно экземпляр класса, который доступен так же по ссылке begindate

Во избежания такой ситуации советую использовать следующую конструкцию, которая будет работать для всех объектов:

`var time = Object.assign({}, begindate);`

или

`var time = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(begindate))`